# What is Blender 2.8 alternative to ctrl+shift+alt+c? (Set Origin in 2.8)

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut

[image]
I don't understand how i can move the orange dot which is my origin to the center of my active object? I could do this before in blender 2.79 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and it was BEYOND useful. Now my whole workflow has slowed to a glacial place because I cant figure out how to centralize the origin point to my *active object* NOT to the center of the whole model?

I need the active point to be in the middle of the highlighted object (building on the top left).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Header menu > *Object* > *Set Origi*n > *Origin To Geometry*. And if you right click on this function you can add it in your *Quick Favorites*. I don't know why they removed the shortcut though.

[image]

Comment: Maybe a shortcut that contained 4 keys should not be a default assign keymap, although it is used pretty often?

Comment: They could have simplified but I thought it was ok, and anyway it's more convenient than the header menu. Same thing for the Timeline, they have removed S and E to set the start and the end, which were pretty convenient. But I guess all these things will come back eventually

Comment: GOD BLESS YOUR SOUL MAN!!!!
It worked!!!

Comment: @moonboots Wait...you can use S and E to set the timeline? No wonder they remove it from short cut, if no one mention it i will never know that fact

Answer (score 3):

Besides the approach described by [@moonboots](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/34531/moonboots) you can also edit the keymap and reintroduce the shortcut. You can find the keymap in *Edit > Preferences > Keymap*.

Navigate through the shortcut hierarchy *3D View > Object Mode > Object Mode (Global)*. Scroll to the end of the existing shortcuts and click on *+ Add New*.

[image: Keymap]

Then configure the shortcut by setting the identifier to `object.origin_set` which is the operator and select the type from the dropdown (*Origin to Geometry*). You can choose whatever key combination you like, just make sure that it's not already used for something else in object mode.

[image: Shortcut]

Comment: great! But I guess it's rather 3D View > Object Mode > Object Mode (Global)?

Comment: @moonboots yes you're right. Fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

There's another option (the one I use): enable the shipped add-on 'Pie Menu: 3D Viewport'. It includes a <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> Origins pie, giving you choices of where to place object origins.

It works on single or multiple objects, even from Edit Mode. (Although it chucks you into Object Mode when done)

It will all be less relevant soon .. in 3.81xxx, we can transform object origins.

Comment: wwow nice thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you press <kbd>W</kbd> you have bunch of useful options including origin settings.